# Refrecar solo una parte de una pagina html

Tags: html

la cosa es que tengo una raspberry pi haciendo streaming a una pagina html, el clásico ejemplo de streaming + control de un led através de GPIO y un botón en la pagina.

El control y el streaming de video funcionan (casi) bien, el problema es que cada vez que apago o prendo el led (mediante click al botón) toda la página se refresca y necesito que el video esté contínuo sin refrescarse.
 Como hago?

Este es mi código de html, el de python lo tengo en un .py

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
        <title>Servidor Web RPi</title>
        <!--ultimaversión compilada de CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!--Tema Opcional-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!--Ultimaversion de Javascript-->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http:code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>


        <script>
                $(document).ready(function){
                        $('#Python').click(function(){
                        $("#contenido").load("main.html");
                        }


        };

</head>

<body>

        <h1>Servidor Web Rpi  Taller de Diseño de Sistemas Embebidos</h1>
        <h1><font color="blue">nombre</font></h1>
        <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="50%">


        {% for pin in pins %}
        <h2>{{ pins[pin].name }}
        {% if pins[pin].state == true %}

                Esta <strong><font color="lime">ENCENDIDO</font></strong></h2><div class="row"><div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="/{{pin}}/off" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default" role="button">Apagar LED</a></div></div>
        {% else %}
                Esta <strong><font color="red">APAGADO</font></strong></h2><div class ="row"><div class=" col-md-2">
                <a href="/{{pin}}/on" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" role="button">Encender LED</a></div></div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```